# Why are the numbers without decimals in the LEP table not the same but different? Shouldn't it be the same according to the rule I marked in red?

Tags: regulations, checklist, diamond-da40

I don't understand the text I framed in red. Because according to the logic of without decimal in the LEP table below, shouldn't the number without decimal be common to every non-decimal?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diamond aircraft have multiple variants under the DA40.  If there is a checklist change that affects all those variants it will get a major number bump.  The next major revision would be 18.

If there is a change that only affects a subset of the aircraft a minor revision is issued with a dot notation.  The next minor revision would be 17.1.

Comment: Let's say for page 4, a new revision is made after the 17.9th edit on a single type of DA40NG. In this case, what will they write in the edition as they cannot write 18?

Comment: @pilot162  that would be the 17.10th edition. This is a very common approach in software release numbering, called [semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) and sometimes also adopted in documentation versioning. Try not to see the the version number as a decimal number, but as two numbers separated by a period (.)

Comment: According to what you said, I think it is necessary to think that it can continue as 17.99999... but it never turns 18? Sorry, I couldn't open the "semantic versioning" link.

Comment: What I want to know is, why the heck is "for" in German on an english language page lol

Comment: @pilot162 If a new revision affects all types, it will become version "18". If it doesn't, the version following "17.9" will be "17.10", then "17.11", then "17.12" and so on. Technically it could go on to "17.99999" and then "17.100000", but realistically there will be a change affecting all versions before, which is version "18".

Comment: Got the logic, thank you Bianfable. By the way, believe me, why "für" is written in German instead of "for", I question it every day ahahahaha @John K.